# iPhone, how to detect when control is returned to browser?

Tags: iphone, flash, safari, youtube, swfobject

I'm a newbie to cocoa programing on iPhone.

My client has a website that plays YouTube videos. Once a video is finished playing, it will automatically play the next one. This is done by using the YouTube API and swfobject.

After some research, I was told that Safari on iPhone does not support flash. This make the current swfobject code not working on the iPhone browser.

As workaround, when the user clicked on an embedded player, iPhone will launch the YouTube app.

Is to possible to determine when the YouTube app has finished playing and has returned control back to browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIWebView to play videos from YouTube. You'll have to control those from your application though (start, stop, play next, etc).

Also In iOS you can register custom URI schemes and then redirect the browser (or UIWebView) back to your application. This is how many application do 3-legged OAuth for example (which requires a browser interaction). Which might require having a control over the server.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible to jump out of your App and then come back to it again.  Once you leave your App, you are finished.

You'll need to stay in a UIWebView, or come up with another method of playing the YouTube videos from within your App.

-t

Comment: Hi Tim:

Thanks for your input. 

I havent tried running the website under the UIWebView. 

However I do try modifying the website so that it uses embedded object instead of swfobject. After that, clicking the link in the Safari browser will fire the YouTube application. 

I will try out your suggestion later when i get my license setup properly on my client's test machine. Meanwhile, will there be any difference between running the website in a UIWebView and iPhone Safari browser?

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: that is not true. In iOS you can register custom URI schemes and then redirect the browser (or UIWebView) back to your application. Many application do it with 3-legged OAuth for example (which requires a browser interaction).